# Store string from file as separate variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file that I am reading from.

The file is formatted by `ID NUMBER,DEPARTMENT` Example:`23942,English` Always 5 digit ID number, department can vary in length.

The first step I was able to do, which was to pull from the first file anyone from the English department.

```
$x = Get-Content -Path C:\dep.txt | Where-Object {$_.Contains("English")}
```

This returns `"00000,English 11111,English 22222,English......etc)"`

However, now I am bit confused. For every `ID NUMBER` that gets returned, I need to store them into a separate variable.

Then I need to take those variables (let's just say a,b,c....etc) and compare them to a second text file that is formatted as `LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ID NUMBER`. Example `Alex,Jones,29472` So using the variables (a,b,c,...etc) I need to locate the corresponding `ID NUMBER` and find the `LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME` that goes with it and write the name to names.txt

I'd appreciate any help I could get with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) is your friend here. You can simply read your file's contents into a PowerShell object. As an object, you can reference its property values and perform conditional searches.

```
$deps = Import-Csv c:\dep.txt # Use this if your file already has column headers
# For English department objects
$deps | Where Department -eq 'English'
# For ID Number values for English Departments
($deps | Where Department -eq 'English').'ID Number'

# Let's match department numbers with people
$people = Import-Csv people.csv
$Ids = ($deps | Where Department -eq 'English').'ID Number'
$people | Where 'ID Number' -in $Ids
```

If your CSV files don't have headers, you can add them to the command with the `-Header` parameter:

```
$deps = Import-Csv c:\dep.txt -Header 'ID Number','Department'
```